# Disk partition showing "Low Disk Space" but cannot delete Windows Backup files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, backup

Windows 7 desktop PC that has been using Windows Backup on a schedule. Unfortunately it has been backing up to the Recovery partition where the original factory software is located. Windows Backup has filled the remaining space in this Recovery partition then crashed and now the Recovery partition continually shows "Low Disk Space" and causes frequent pop-ups from Windows that it needs attention. When I examine the Recovery partition there is only the factory software present (well within the partition size) and there is no sign of the Windows Backup files. This is the case even if "Show hidden files and folders" is switched on and "Hide protected operating system files" is switched off. How can I delete the offending Windows Backup files and hence get rid of the Low Disk Space warning messages? Windows Backup does not list any old Backups for deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel, under System and Security, go to Backup and Restore. Click on "Change Settings", on that screen, there will be a button to "View backups..." click on that and you can click on specific backups to delete.